# C# SerialPort doesn't support high baud rate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

I am using Silicon Labs CP210x driver for my USB to UART bridge. Using CVAVR's terminal, I can receive data from the bridge using 57600 baud rate. However, when I implemented this on C#, I got an OutOfRange exception stating the maximum baud rate the device can support is 24302. I tried reinstall the driver then restarted the computer. The limit is now pulled down to 14300 baud rate. I can't receive data properly using 9600 baud rate. Changing .Net Framework target version didn't help either. What should I do?

Comment: The driver should work at high speeds according to web.  Make sure you have latest driver from following site : https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software

Comment: @jdweng I have installed the latest driver from the web and the error remains the same. Just now I tried using putty to read from the bridge and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you reading using Sync or Asyns.  Since doesn't work well so I usually use Async.

Comment: I use async to read from serial

Comment: Do you have any timers/waits  in you code.  They are not needed with Async and can cause issues.  The problem may not be with the Async read code it could be elsewhere.  Check Task Manager a see what load is happening om Performance tab.   Is the data binary or Ascii.  How are you handling the end of each message.

Comment: I use CP210x drivers with all our products and most of our devices run at 115200 baud.  There shouldn't be an issue here.  Which driver did you download?  There website can be a little confusing.  I think you want v6.7.5, not the v10.1.1.

Comment: @Baddack It worked! Thank you so much. I suspected driver problem but didn't think there are more than one version of the driver. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix the issue. :)

Comment: @swdmnd: write an answer to your question saying it was a driver issue, then accept your own answer. That way, everyone will know the question was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a driver issue. I got my driver from https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers. There are many versions available there. Version 10.1.3 didn't work on my Windows 10 system, but 6.7.5 worked.